# Present table cells as links in Plone (Novice)

Tags: html, css, plone

New here - and sorry to say; I am an HTML novice.

I am trying to use **table cells** as **links** in **Plone**. I want to create the illusion of 'tabs' (as this is not available in the current CSS) and don't want the text to be underlined, but I also want the function for another page where cells direct to another page.

I tried a few suggestions online which don't seem to work as it makes the first cell underlined and only the text is linked. e.g.:

```
<td><a href="http://example.com"> hello world </a></td>
```

My table row currently looks like:

```html
<table class="data">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="green" style="text-align: center; ">Tab A</th>
      <th class="white" style="text-align: center; ">
        <a class="internal-link" href="www.google.com"></a>Tab B</th>
      <th class="white" style="text-align: center; ">Tab C</th>
      <th class="white" style="text-align: center; ">Tab D</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need all these cells to link to other pages, i.e.  as if they were linked images.

Comment: You may generally have better luck posting questions on our forum, https://community.plone.org (more eyeballs), though I posted a link on the forum to your question here

Comment: Avoid tables, use lists instead: https://www.thoughtco.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```css
table.data th > a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 5px;
 }
```

```html
<table class="data">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="green"><a href="http://example1.com">Tab A</a></th>
      <th class="white"><a href="http://example2.com">Tab B</a></th>
      <th class="white"><a href="http://example3.com">Tab C</a></th>
      <th class="white"><a href="http://example3.com">Tab D</a></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Vinit. Unfortunately, the first part of the code remains as text and I get the table with linked words after it; as before... Should I prefix the table.data th > a { with something to render it?

Comment: The first part of the code is the CSS. You need to add it in CSS file or if there isn't a CSS file you can always add it inside `<style>` tag in your file.

Comment: Thanks Vinit. Please can you give me an example? I can't use CSS as the predefined Plone system strips it out.

Comment: @PinkFruitcake Sounds like you're trying to insert your snippet into the body-text of a content-item. What is your exact use-case? Maybe a navigation-portlet can help you here.